# Repeating Image Wrapped Around H3 Tag

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a website and I ran across a little dilemma...

I've got an h3 tag that needs a repeating background on both sides..It's kind of hard to explain so I made this graphic...

[image]

Basically its a title with a repeating background on both sides of it but the background stops where the title begins and then continues afterward...I've played around with a ton of CSS but no luck...Any ideas?

Comment: I tried making a div on each side of the title and floating one left and one right and giving those repeating backgrounds which works but there's not way to know what the width should be when you change the title...if the title is short the left and right divs wrapping around need to be bigger

Comment: did you look at `:before` and `:after`?  Or CSS3 `border-image`?

Comment: To clarify what Matt said, `:before` and `:after` are layers that you can use to generate that type of content.

Comment: yeah not looking to use CSS3 because it won't work on older browsers but I'm not too familiar with :before and :after can you provide an example?

Comment: i know this is an obvious answer, but what about this http://jsfiddle.net/WXSNp/1/, or am i missing something?

Comment: `h3:before,h3:after { width: ...; background-image: url(...); display: inline-block; }` Something along those lines should work.

Comment: intelis - yes the background pattern should not continue behind the text

Comment: I tried the before and after but it didn't work..I'll js fiddle it and post in a min

Comment: @user1647347, sorry..you need `content: "";`.  Answer with jsfiddle posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of `:before` and `:after`

http://jsfiddle.net/JTN2U/ - Season to taste

Comment: The only issue is the width...when you change the title text the width needs to change...is it possible for the bg to stretch to the end of the div?

Comment: If you're looking for a solution where the background pads to a fixed width, you'd be better off having a container on the outside with a fixed width and background image and then the h3 with a solid white to cover it.

Comment: The problem is the solid white to cover doesn't match my page background pattern

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/hXw5x/1/ - or whatever you want to match the background other than white, do you need a transparent background or could you just set the background to the underlying background?

Comment: the real div background is a paper texture so setting the background to a solid color doesn't work well

Comment: You'll likely have to use JavaScript to do it cleanly.  CSS normally only has the context of an elements direct ancestry in most browsers, and calculating remaining width after rendering is outside of that capability.

Comment: yeah I'll try and figure out a jquery trick for figuring out the width and use your example above ...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I think you might need to put another tag within your h3 like this:

```
<h3><span class="text">title goes here</span></h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 {
  background: url('img.jpg') repeat-x;
  padding: 0 20px; /* or however much of the image you want to show */
}

h3 .text {
  background: #fff; /* or whatever background color */
}
```

**Update:**
HTML:

```
<h3><span class="pre"></span><span class="text">title goes here</span><span class="post"></span></h3>
```

CSS:

```
h3 span.pre,
h3 span.post {
  background: url('header-bg.jpg') repeat-x;
  display: block;
  width: 20px;
  float: left;
}

h3 span.text {
  float: left;
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I tried this but the problem is the background color. The background of this container is a pattern so I cant use css to block out the background behind the title text :/

Comment: Can you use that same background on the span instead of the `#fff`?

Comment: I can but it's a fairly complex "noise" pattern so it doesn't look seamless :/

Comment: Updated answer with another option

Comment: Yeah that works but the page bg image looks doesn't line up right with the real page background since the pattern is crazy

Comment: Sorry the span.text shouldn't have the background image on it. I'll update answer.

Answer (score 0):

Add the repeat-x background to `h3` then you can add a span tag inside. There are many other ways you can do this.

[See the demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/7XcMJ/)

Comment: Yeah that would work except my page background is a texture background image...even if I use a snipped of the real background image you can tell that the pattern doesn't align :/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is a suitable solution as its not one single tag....

```
<style type="text/css">
  div {background-image: url('navlolite.gif'); text-align: center;}
  label {background-color: #FFFFFF; padding-left: 24px; padding-right: 24px;}
</style>

<div>
  <label>My Headng Text</label>
</div>
```